# Curl Command for getting a file from location

Tags: curl

'I am trying to copy specific file from a location using curl using '

'curl -O -u userId:Password https://www.someName.com/Package/local/random.zip'

'where userId and Password is credentials to access the url'

'It is forming a zip file that is coming to be empty. I checked on the url the file has content of about 30MB'

Comment: One thing worth trying is running the command again but with the `-v` (or `--verbose`) flag and observe the headers. That usually gives a pretty good view of what's going on right away.

Answer (score 0):

To download you just need to use curl command like this

`curl --user username:password -o filename.zip https://www.someName.com/Package/local/random.zip`

Comment: Thanks For the Response @ Thusitha Sumanadasa.
It Helped, something Happened for sure, instead of getting blank file.
But I got "SEC_E_Cert_Expired error". It says certificate has already expired. 
Any Idea?